# Error:Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to the beta version of Android Studio (0.8.0) from a canary build (0.6.0 i believe) I am getting a `Error:Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants` error from Android Studio when trying to refresh my project.

Here is the log:

```
2014-06-27 17:05:52,702 [ 709722]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:269)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Edit
After removing `apply plugin: 'android-test'` from one of my modules that error is resolved.

Now I am getting:

```
    Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
    Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
...
...
```

In D:\Users(User)\AndroidStudioProjects(Project)\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.0-rc1\res\values-v21\values.xml

I do have the latest SDK downloaded so I'm not sure what the problem is...

Comment: Replace the android-test plugin with robolectric-gradle.

Answer (score 3):

Check your appCompat-v7 version.
It has a problem with backward compatibility that the newest one (21.0.0-rc1) tries to link UI components to Android L's Material ones. (But of course it fails because you just upgraded AndroidStudio version and not introduce the newest SDK!)
So a possible fix is to specify appCompat-v7's version in build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That was moved to `com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants`. Assuming that you are using `BuilderConstants` in your `build.gradle` file, you will need to adjust it to refer to the new package.

Comment: @orrett3: Without seeing your `build.gradle` file, it is difficult to comment. You might also consider posting a separate question on that, as it would not appear to be related to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  What **tacke** suggested worked for me.  The problem showed up when I imported an Eclipse library project into Android Studio.

In the app module, Android Studio created this in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

I had to change the compile referring to appcompat-v7:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

(note the addition of a ":19.+" in **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'**)

Then I made sure my Compile Sdk Version was 19: (File->Project Structure->Compile Sdk Version) = 19.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a dependency in my test libraries that caused this problem. If you compile your app on the command line with:

```
gradle --stacktrace
```

You'll see the line of code in your build.gradle file that is causing this problem.  You probably need to update the version.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the target and compile version to L which meant that I could not run my app on older SDKs. If you want your app to run on SDK 19 and lower you have to set your compile and target version to 19 and your min SDK to whatever version you need.

Next you have to adjust your imports to the version that is compatible with the SDKs that you have chosen to compile for. For example if you want to use the v7 support library on sdk 19 you must import it like this: compile compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an **import statement** in your build.gradle file?  Like:
`import com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants`.  If so, then your **build.gradle** needs to have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

at the top right after the import statement.